# Passing data to two views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass a variable from a controller to two view files.

```
    public function post($id) {
    $data['query'] = $this->blog_model->get_post($id);
    $data['comments'] = $this->blog_model->get_post_comment($id);
    $data['post_id'] = $id;
    $data['total_comments'] = $this->blog_model->total_comments($id);
```

I want to pass the [total_comments] variable to the index.php and post.php views. How do I do that? Can I pass data to a view without loading them like this:

```
     $this->load->view('post',$data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along this lines?

```
$data['post'] = $this->load->view('post',$data, TRUE);
```

The `'TRUE'` argument tells CI to call your view and place it in a `$data['post']` variable. Later on you can use that variable in another view and just print it out.

edit:

I'm not sure how you have organized your controllers and views but lets say something like this. This is just an example:

**controller**

```
 public function comments() {
        $data['comments'] = $this->comments_model->get_all_comments();
        $data['someVariable'] = 123;
        $this->load->view('header', $data);          //load header view
        $data['sidebar'] = $this->load->view('sidebar', $data, TRUE);   //put sidebar view in a variable, but don't show it immediately 
        $this->load->view('comments', $data);        //load comments view

        $this->load->view('footer'. $data);          //load footer view
    }
```

Whenever you pass `$data` to a controller you are passing the whole `$data` array to that view so you can access all of its elements in a view.

For example in your comments.php view you will have `$comments`, `$someVariable` and `$sidebar` variables so you can do whatever you want with them.

In comments.php you'd probably have something like this:

**comments.php**

```
<div id="comments"> 
<?php 
   foreach($comments as $c){       //print out all found comments
?>
   <div class="comment">
      <?= $c['commentauthor'] ?> <br />
      <?= $c['commenttext'] ?>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
  <?= $sidebar ?>       //print out sidebar
</div>

<p> This is some variable: <?= $someVariable ?> </p>
```

Those same variables are available in the footer view, because you've passed $data to that view

```
$this->load->view('footer'. $data);
```

I hope that this makes things a bit more clear to you.

Comment: OK can you explain me how to pass it to index and post view files

Comment: I see what you saying,BUT I need to pass data to index view without loading it. Other way like I loaded post,$data .I need to get $data variable to index view from post view.

Comment: well i'm not sure what do you mean, 'without loading'. `$this->load->view('index', $data, TRUE);` will pass `$data` to index view without printing the view. Just like 'sidebar' view in the example above